# Vue & JavaScript error. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Прошу помощи, в vue новый. Скачал скрипт админ панели
И нужно в vue view подключить в шаблоне JS файлы админской панели

Делаю так:

```
<script>
      import Apex from "apexcharts";
      import jQuery from "jquery";

      import '../../assets/js/app.min'

      import '../../assets/js/pages/demo.dashboard.js'


export default {
    name: "Index",
   // components: {AdminDashboardLayout},
    data: function () {
        return {}
    },
}
```

и в файле App.min содержится код, и начинается он так

```
!function (i) {
"use strict";

function t() {
    this.body = i("body"), this.window = i(window), this.menuContainer = i("#leftside-menu-container")
}
....
```

И Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю обычный файл панели, без vue, то все js отлично работают,
но у меня всё идет плохо и при запуске даёт ошибку [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryLP1.png)

И по моему проблема в неверном подключении файлов js, но подключить их так же как в файле без vue я не могу, потому что в template нельзя подключать через script tag. Я пробовал разные своеобразные методы что то в роде
document.head.addChild... *и тут был тег скрипт* , но vue не дал мне этого сделать

Мучаюсь уже второй день, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Когда скрипты подключаются через import, они работают как независимые модули, и переменные и функции, объявленные в одном скрипте, не видны в других. По-видимому, в App.min делается попытка вызвать функцию из другого скрипта. Посмотрите в конце файла, где делается собственно сам вызов.

Вам действительно нужно подключать эти скрипты через template. Не знаю, какой CMS вы пользуетесь, но в ней наверняка должны быть средства подключения скриптов.

Вот, например, как это делается в Битриксе (это не надо копировать в ваш код, это только пример):

```
<?
$APPLICATION->AddHeadString("<script type='module' src='{$templateFolder}/vue/AppOffer.js'></script>");
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/js/filter-list-map.js");
?>
```

То есть я указываю системе подключить скрипт с компонентом Vue, нужным для страницы, как модуль, и другой скрипт - как обычно.